# magit rebasing uses $EDITOR=vim

Tags: windows, git, emacs, magit

I have emacs and git installed for windows (have to use windows for work), everything seems ok when I commit, the comment message pops up in emacs nicely, but when rebasing, I select 'interactively' from magit, I get to choose a commit to rebase on, then I press 'C-c C-c', it supposes to switch to `git-rebase-todo` buffer, but instead I got `magit-process` buffer, it appears git tries to use vim and stuck there:

```
run C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git.exe … "rebase" "-i" "55ec1e8^"
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal

Press ENTER or type command to continue[?1000l[?25h
```

It appears magit doesn't modify $EDITOR when rebasing, how do I force magit use emacs? Thank you.

Comment: You can use `setenv` to set variables in Emacs's environment, which should be inherited by any processes it starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, it's nothing to do with windows, I have `sequence.editor` option in gitconfig, it appears magit cannot overwrite this option.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), especially on Windows: an editor session launched during a Git operation (e.g. during '[`git commit`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/853ec9aa9be1b467986dd86ffc36c1c8580a6789/Documentation/git-commit.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit))</sup>) or `git rebase` can leave the terminal in a funny state.

> The code path has updated to save the terminal state before, and restore it after, it spawns an editor.

See [commit 3d411af](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d411afabc9a96f41d47c07d6af6edda3d29ec92), [commit e22b245](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e22b245ea576bf1787284971b467f45f45045f97) (05 Oct 2021) by [Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón (`carenas`)](https://github.com/carenas).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 853ec9a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/853ec9aa9be1b467986dd86ffc36c1c8580a6789), 18 Oct 2021)</sup>

> ### [`editor`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d411afabc9a96f41d47c07d6af6edda3d29ec92): save and reset terminal after calling `EDITOR`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón</sup>

> When EDITOR is invoked to modify a commit message, it will likely change the terminal settings, and if it misbehaves will leave the terminal output damaged as shown in a recent report from [Windows Terminal (issue 9359)](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/9359)
>
> Instead use the functions provided by compat/terminal to save the settings and recover safely.

Example of the error you can get:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/929932/110089418-6354cb80-7d96-11eb-8544-22c30c4a3a35.png]